# dealing with bitmap as if it was an array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, bitmap

well, i wonder if one writes code to show a bitmap on a form. 
Would it be possible to access it directly like an array in c#?

I am wondering this because the bitmap is already there in memory and on screen.
But I'm not sure on how to point to it; like it where a pointer or array so, I want to do this in c# and I also don't know the array data structure on the form (like is it RGB BGR / RGB24 etc)

As a note, this image source isn't from a file, it's from a webcam.
Also, a reason I want to do this is because getpixel / putpixel is to slow for what I want.

Comment: [BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370(v=vs.85).aspx) is fast but not C# I dont know how performance is if you [pInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32.bitblt) it

Comment: [DrawImageUnscaled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimageunscaled.aspx) could be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the image pixels in the array you can do it like this:

```
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap("somebitmap.png");
            Rectangle area = new Rectangle(0,0,image.Width, image.Height);
            BitmapData bitmapData = image.LockBits(area, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            int stride = bitmapData.Stride;
            IntPtr ptr = bitmapData.Scan0;
            int numBytes = bitmapData.Stride * image.Height;
            byte[] rgbValues = new byte[numBytes];
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, numBytes);
```

And when you change them you should copy that array back to the Bitmap using this:

```
            Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, bitmapData.Stride * image.Height);
            image.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
```

But if you realy want to deal with pixels like you said, you should use some [FastBitmap](http://code.google.com/p/renderterrain/source/browse/trunk/Utilities/FastBitmap.cs?r=18) implementation. There are many other implementations available also.

Comment: wel yes i want real fast or rather say <b>extreme<b> fast pixel manipulation. But for the moment not yet through GPU of multi-threading. therefor i was thinking of some direct access without copying the bitmap data to other variables.

Comment: @user613326 Then use some FastBitmap implementation. Find the best that suits you. I have used it to rotate Rectangles on CompactFramework (since there are no transformations) and it meet the criteria. Therefore I think it will do for you on the desktop.

Comment: You should really take the `PixelFormat` _from the image_ when executing `LockBits`, rather than assuming it...

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible - even easy - to access a bitmap in C# ... like an array. Use the Bitmap class:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(640, 480);
Color pixel = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);    // "array like" access
bmp.SetPixel(x,y, Color.FromArgb(red,green,blue);
```

The trick in your case is getting the bitmap into the Bitmap class. If it's already on the form, you could create a "graphics context" and retrieve it from that:

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(640, 480, g);
```

Or from a control:

```
Graphics g = this.MyControl.CreateGraphics();
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(640, 480, g);
```

You don't need to worry about it's internal RGB(A) format, just deal with the 'Color' type and set/get it's R/G/B components as you wish.

Comment: Ehm yes but getpixel en putpixel are known to be verry slow
so therefore i was thinking about array access (i'l update the question with this).

Comment: True but speed wasn't mentioned in the question ;) But once you have the graphics context, you could use it's blitting support for speed instead of accessing the Bitmap pixels individually (then access the blit destination as an array); see Graphics.CopyFromScreen(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

The pixels in a bitmap are not exposed via an array i.e. mybitmap[x,y].

You can use the GetPixel(x,y) method to access the color value of a specific pixel, or SetPixel(x,y) to change the value.